# Calling a VBA Macro with Parameters from Backstage

Tags: office-2010

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181863/vba-cannot-find-my-macro-when-it-has-parameters) I was having problems debugging a Macro with Parameters that I want to use in Office 2010 backstage.

The answer to that question explains why I could not debut the Macro, but I am still having problems with calling the Macro.

The macro is called by clicking a button in a Backstage tab.  There are multiple buttons that call the macro, each one calls it with different parameters.  An example call is as follows:

```
 <button id="bb1" label="MFLLP Portrait" style="large" onAction="NewDocs (Blank, Portrait.dot)" imageMso="FileSaveAsWordDocx" />
```

Macros are set as Fully enabled in the Trust Center, yet when I click on any button I get the message

> The Macro cannot be found or has been disabled in because of your Macro security settings

I can't see any further settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnAction` has never taken parameters, in any version of Word. The way around it for most people is to assign a tag to the control and then get that tag from the `onAction` routine, parse as needed.

The tag will be textual, so you'll just need some good parsing logic, like if you had in your tag "2,True,Blue" then you would split the string, the the first part of the array would be some set of integer value, the next would be boolean values and the next could be color or string values".

This is a complete pain in the @#$ - but it is exactly what all of us VBA devs have been doing over the years to pass parameters.

Comment: If that's the case that's insane.  I suppose the other alternative is to have a specific macro for each button, that then calls exe with the appropriate parameters (or passes them onto the "main" macro)

Comment: @Dan Kelly: Indeed. That's what I used to do in the beginning. As my parameter needs grew, I ended up with the parsed `.Tag` solution, but if you've only got a few different parameterized routines, it should be simple enough to manage them in separate routines.